# Qt Project Management with subprojects: Accessing classes from another project

Tags: c++, qt, project

I am developing a large application that I wish to separate into 3 sub projects for organization and testing's sake; a model, a view, and a controller to act as a middle class between the two.

Here is the structure I have currently:

```
/Project
| Project.pro
|--- MODEL
|    |--- MODEL.pro
|    `--- ...source files
|--- VIEW
|    |--- VIEW.pro
|    `--- ... source files
|--- CONTROLLER
|    |--- CONTROLLER.pro
|    `--- ...source files
```

My Project.pro looks like this

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    VIEW \
    CONTROLLER \
    MODEL

# where to find the sub projects
VIEW.subdir = VIEW
MODEL.subdir = MODEL
CONTROLLER.subdir = CONTROLLER

# what subproject depends on others
CONTROLLER.depends = VIEW MODEL
```

I have a class MainWindow in VIEW. How can I add a reference to it in my CONTROLLER project so that I can use this MainWindow class in, for instance, the `main.cpp` in CONTROLLER?

A simple "#include mainwindow.h" does not suffice. as I get a "No such file or directory". Is there a way to explicitly point it towards the class of another object? Do I have to add a dependency somewhere in the project files?

Comment: You can simply include it. Or what exactly is the problem you have with it?

Comment: @Jaa-c perhaps the issue is that I'm not sure how to include it. A simple "#include mainwindow.h" does not suffice. as I get a "No such file or directory". Is there a way to explicitly point it towards the class of another object? Do I have to add a dependency somewhere in the project files?

Comment: Try putting `INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/..` to your controller.pro and then `#include VIEW/mainwindow.h`?

Comment: @Jaa-c You left this detail out but I find this relevant: I would prefer `#include <VIEW/mainwindow.h>` over `#include "VIEW/mainwindow.h"` although I belief it would work in either case.

Answer (score 1):

In each of your pro file, setup your includepath like this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/..
```

Then, you can include files like

```
#include "VIEW/mainwindow.h"
```

Also if you will build subprojects to separate dll files, you will have to add dependecy of the dll like this:

```
LIBS += -lView
```

Also note that most likely, you should include controller to your view, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Are your dependent projects libraries? I am not sure, but this feature might be intended to use it only with dynamic linkage.

See TEMPLATE = lib examples in Qt documentation

Comment: And by the way, I am succesfully using TEMPLATE = subdirs in one of my projects, and this top .pro file looks just fine